# CouchDB bulk update won't create document if needed

Tags: couchdb, bulk

I am optimizing a script I wrote last year that reads documents from a source Couch db, modified the doc and writes the new doc into a destination Couch db.

So the previous version of the script did the following
1.read a document from source db
2.modify document
3.writes doc into destination db

What I'm trying to do is to pile the docs to write in a list and then write a bulk of the (let's say 100) to the destination db to optimize perfomances.

What I found out is that when the bulk upload has to write a list of docs into the destination db if there is a doc in the list which has an "_id" which does not exist into the destination db, then that document won't be written.

The return value will have "success: true" even if after they copy happened there is no such doc in the destination db.

I tried disabling "delayed_commits" and using the flag "all_or_nothing" but nothing has changed. Cannot find info on stackoverflow / documentation so I'm quite lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To the future generations: what I was experiencing is known Bug and it should be fixed in the next release.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1415

The actual workaround is to write a document that is slighty different each time. I added a useless field called "timestamp" that has as value the timestamp of when i run my script.